# Chef Template DSL - how to load a hash from json and iterate keys and values

Tags: ruby, chef-infra

I have the below code in a chef template but get error when uploading to chef server.  How do I resolve?

```
<%
    contents_hash = File.read('/tmp/cluster_hash')
        neoservers_hash  = JSON.parse(contents_hash)
-%>

<% "#{neoservers_hash}".each_pair do |id, ipaddress| %>
<%= "server.#{id}=#{ipaddress}:2888:3888" %>
<% end %>
```

When I try to upload the cookbook, I get the following error:

```
$ knife cookbook upload neo4j -E development
Uploading neo4j          [0.1.0]
FATAL: Erb template templates/default/coord.cfg.erb has a syntax error:
FATAL: -:7: syntax error, unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting '}'
FATAL:  _buf << ( "server.#{id}=#{ipaddress}:2888:3888" ).to_s; _buf << '
FATAL:                   ^
FATAL: -:8: unterminated string meets end of file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a weird syntax in this line:

```
<% "#{neoservers_hash".each_pair do |id, ipaddress| %>
```

You seem to try to use string evaluation with the `neoserver_hash` variable, which will not really work, as `neoserver_hash` is a Hash and not a String. Also you are missing the closing brace. Instead, you probably want to get rid of the string evaluation completely and use something like this:

```
<% neoservers_hash.each_pair do |id, ipaddress| %>
```

Comment: If you fix that typo, that fundamentally changes the premise of your question. Because that typo (and the wrong string evaluation) is the whole reason for the error.

Comment: the error is the same.  It was not a type when running the code